# How to swap odd and even words in each line?

Tags: bash, text-processing, string

I have a bash script that swaps odd and even strings in one file, and saves it to another:

```
#!/bin/bash

infile="inputfile"
outfile="outputfile"

{
while read -r odd && read -r even
do
    echo "$even"
    echo "$odd"
    unset odd
done < "$infile"

# in case there are an odd number of lines in the file, print the last "odd" line read
if [[ -n $odd ]]; then
    echo "$odd"
fi
} > "$outfile"
```

How can I swap odd and even **words** in each line of the file?

Example:

Input file:

```
one two three four five six
apple banana cocoa dish fish nuts
```

Output file:

```
two one four three six five
banana apple dish cocoa nuts fish
```

Comment: [edit] your question to state and show your requirements if there were an odd number of words on a line. Include in your example a line with just 1 word and a line with 3 words.

Answer (score 6):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne 'put .words.rotor(2).map(*.reverse);'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne '.words.rotor(2).map(*.reverse).put;'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne '.words.rotor(2)>>.reverse.put;'
```

Sample Input:

```
one two three four five six
apple banana cocoa dish fish nuts
```

Sample Output:

```
two one four three six five
banana apple dish cocoa nuts fish
```

Above are answers coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Briefly: `raku` is invoked at the command line using the `-ne` linewise non-autoprinting flag(s). When using either the `-ne` or `-pe` command line flags, each line loads into `$_`, a.k.a. Raku's "topic variable" (`$_` is also the "topic variable" in Perl). A leading `.` dot is shorthand for `$_.` signifying that the methods that follow are to be applied to `$_`, the topic variable. Successive methods are chained together with the `.` dot operator, each transforming the input data in turn.

Going through the methods: we see the linewise input is broken on whitespace into `words`,  then `rotor`-ed together into pairs of words (i.e. an argument of `2` is supplied). The name of the `rotor` function may be a bit obscure, but I'm guessing it is meant to signify that individual elements of a data object are cycled or `rotor`-ed through and grouped/clustered together. After `rotor`-ing, each pair is individually addressed using `map`, and the `reverse` function applied. Finally, the output in printed with `put`.

Note, the code above (using `rotor` defaults) will drop any "incomplete sets of elements" at the end. To retain "incomplete sets of elements" at the end, either change the `rotor` call to add a True `partial` parameter, or use `batch` which means the same thing:

```perl
raku -ne 'put .words.rotor(2, partial => True).map(*.reverse);'
```

Which is the same as:

```perl
raku -ne 'put .words.rotor(2, :partial).map(*.reverse);'
```

Which is the same as:

```perl
raku -ne 'put .words.batch(2).map(*.reverse);'
```

https://raku.org

Answer (score 4):

I propose this `sed`, suggested by @guest_7:

```bsh
$ sed -e 's/\([^ ]\+\) \([^ ]\+\)/\2 \1/g' inputfile 
two one four three six five 
banana apple dish cocoa nuts fish
```

Answer (score 3):

Using`perl` it can be accomplished via clipping two leading elements from the input array of words (@F), flip them, and then append to the output array (@A)

```bsh
perl -slane 'my @A;
  push @A, reverse splice @F, 0, 2
    while @F > 1;
  print @A, @F;
' -- -,=\  ./yourfile
```

---

Using the shell itself

```bsh
cat yourfile |
while IFS= read -r l
do
  set -f; set -- $l
  while [ "$#" -gt 1 ]
  do
    printf '%s ' "$2" "$1"
    shift 2
  done
  echo "${1-}"
done
```

---

```bsh
awk '
{
  t=$0;$0="";split(t, a)
  for (i=1; i+1 in a; i+=2) {
    $(i) = a[i+1]
    $(i+1) = a[i]
  }
  if (i in a) $(i) = a[i]
}1
' yourfile
```

---

With `python`, we make use of list slicing and list comprehension features:

```
python3 -c 'import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
  for l in f:
    F = l.strip().split()+[""]
    print(*[f"{b} {a}" for a,b in zip(F[::2],F[1::2])])
' yourfile
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
k=open('file1','r')
for line in k:
    fina_list=[]
    con=line.strip().split(' ')
    for raco in range(0,len(con),2):
        if (int(raco)%2 == 0):
            odd_cha=con[raco+1]
            even_cha=con[raco]
            con[raco]=odd_cha
            con[raco+1]=even_cha
            fina_list.append(con[raco])
            fina_list.append(con[raco+1])
    print " ".join(fina_list)
```

output

```
two one four three six five
banana apple dish cocoa nuts fish
```